# How to refresh div with updated php code in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, partial-page-refresh

Within a jQuery Mobile page, I have a div which needs to be refreshed after a php mysql JSON call is made. This call updates the number of entries in a database. This update needs to be displayed within the div. I searched stackoverflow and found .listview("refresh"), .trigger("create") and other potential solutions but could not get to work. I think .listview("refresh") is not applicable since I am not using a list.

The main page has two mobile pages within it #outerwrap0 and #outerwrap1:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="models/site-templates/themes/whiteBackNavy.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/shuffleMainJplayerJQM1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--*** PAGE 0 ***-->
<div data-role="page" id='outerwrap0' class="outerwrap" data-url="/account_m.php">
     <div class="mineBox">
     ... php ...
     </div
</div

<!--*** PAGE 1 ***-->
<div data-role="page" id='outerwrap1' class="outerwrap" data-url="/account_m.php">
     <div class="mineBox">
     ... php ...
     </div
</div
```

the applicable portion of the shuffleMainJplayerJQM1.1.js javascript, wherein the php is updated and code should be called to refresh the div is:

```
$(".adder").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'AddToMine1.2.php?id=' + currentId,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success : function (result) {
            var errorCode = (result['errorCode']);      
            switch (errorCode) {
                case 0: alert(result['errorMess']); 
                    break;
                case 1: alert(result['errorMess']); 
                    break;
                case 2: break;
            }
        },
        error : function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    }); 
    // not working - would like to refresh mineBox div here
    $(".mineBox").trigger("create");
});
```

Here is the contents of .mineBox after rendering:

```
<div class="mineBox">
        <p align=center>
            <a href="#popupMenuPM1" data-rel="popup"><img src="../images/mine_block_full.jpg" width="14%" align="absmiddle" /></a>
        </p>
        <p align=center><a href="#popupMenuPM2" data-rel="popup"><img src="../images/mine_block_full.jpg" width="14%" align="absmiddle" /></a>
        </p>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenuPM1" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
                <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Be</li>
                <li><a href="#" class="counter" data-rank="1" data-id="399" data-song_name="Be" data-file_name="02Be.mp3">Play</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenuPM2" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
                <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Want Girl</li>
                <li><a href="#" class="counter" data-rank="2" data-id="418" data-song_name="Want Girl" data-file_name="10WantGirl.mp3">Play</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: What kind of items are you adding? anyway, try `$.mobile.activePage.trigger("pagecreate");`

Comment: Adding block images each of which represent a clickable song file. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: As long as you're not using any jQM widget, this wont help. Before you append new items or update div, use `$(".mineBox").empty()` and then add items.

Comment: A slight clarification: the page starts with block images in .minebox div, then the block images need to be updated with the script. So how do I update the div after `$(".mineBox").empty()`? With normal (non-mobile) jQuery I had been using `(".mineBox").load("pyrMineJQM.php");` which updated the div.

Comment: `.load()` adds items, but doesn't overwrite div contents. `.empty()` removes all elements within that div.

Comment: I seem to be able to load the div using `.empty()` and then `.load()` per your advice but now the jquery mobile scripts (i.e. popups) do not seem to work within the `.mineBox` div . So I guess the DOM Head scripts are not loading. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I cant assist you without further details. Please post some code of the loaded elements after being rendered. It could be binding event to dynamically added items problem.

Comment: I have added sample rendered `.minebox` content as edit to original question.

Comment: thanks. page div should be the direct parent of popup div in order to have it work properly. You have two options, either load popups separately under page div, or create them dynamically once img/button clicked http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kw74g/

Comment: the popups load fine the first time around. Just after: `$(".mineBox").empty();` and `$(".mineBox").load();` they don't really work. It seems to "almost" work - but I think the problem is that the original javascripts in the page head are not firing (leading to other problems besides popup). Do you have any suggestions regarding keeping all page head javascript functionality after the refresh?

Comment: if you load an html file using `.load()`, inside that file add this js line `$("[data-role=popup]").popup().trigger("create");`.